# To improve Calculate Number of Days Command

Tags: unix, awk

Would like to generate report, which calculate the number of days, the material is in the warehouse. 
The number of days is the difference between date `($3 field)` the material comes in and 
against  `(01 OCT 2014)` manual feed date.

Input.csv

```
Des11,Material,DateIN,Des22,Des33,MRP,Des44,Des55,Des66,Location,Des77,Des88
aa,xxx,19-AUG-14.08:08:01,cc,dd,x20,ee,ff,gg,XX128,hh,jj
aa,xxx,19-AUG-14.08:08:01,cc,dd,x20,ee,ff,gg,XX128,hh,jj
aa,yyy,13-JUN-14.09:06:08,cc,dd,x20,ee,ff,gg,XX128,hh,jj
aa,yyy,13-JUN-14.09:06:08,cc,dd,x20,ee,ff,gg,XX128,hh,jj
aa,yyy,05-FEB-14.09:02:09,cc,dd,x20,ee,ff,gg,YY250,hh,jj
aa,yyy,05-FEB-14.09:02:09,cc,dd,y35,ee,ff,gg,YY250,hh,jj
aa,zzz,05-FEB-14.09:02:09,cc,dd,y35,ee,ff,gg,YY250,hh,jj
aa,zzz,11-JUN-13.05:06:17,cc,dd,y35,ee,ff,gg,YY250,hh,jj
aa,zzz,11-JUN-13.05:06:17,cc,dd,y35,ee,ff,gg,YY250,hh,jj
aa,zzz,11-JUN-13.05:06:17,cc,dd,y35,ee,ff,gg,YY250,hh,jj
```

Currently i am using below command to popualte Ageing - No of days at $13 field ( `thanks to gboffi`)

```
awk -F, 'NR>0  {date=$3;
                  gsub("[-.]"," ",date);
                  printf $0 ",";system("date --date=\"" date "\" +%s")}
  '  Input.csv | awk -F, -v OFS=, -v now=`date --date="01 OCT 2014 " +%s` '
                  NR>0  {$13=now-$13; $13=$13/24/3600;print $0}' >Op_Step11.csv
```

while using the above command in Cygwin (windows), it is taking `50 minutes for 1 Lac (1,00,000)` rows of sample input.
Since my actual input file contains `25 million rows of lines` , it seems that the script will take couple of days ,
Looking for your suggestions to improve the command and advice !!!

Expected Output:

```
Des11,Material,DateIN,Des22,Des33,MRP,Des44,Des55,Des66,Location,Des77,Des88,Ageing-NoOfDays
aa,xxx,19-AUG-14.08:08:01,cc,dd,x20,ee,ff,gg,XX128,hh,jj,42.6611
aa,xxx,19-AUG-14.08:08:01,cc,dd,x20,ee,ff,gg,XX128,hh,jj,42.6611
aa,yyy,13-JUN-14.09:06:08,cc,dd,x20,ee,ff,gg,XX128,hh,jj,109.621
aa,yyy,13-JUN-14.09:06:08,cc,dd,x20,ee,ff,gg,XX128,hh,jj,109.621
aa,yyy,05-FEB-14.09:02:09,cc,dd,x20,ee,ff,gg,YY250,hh,jj,237.624
aa,yyy,05-FEB-14.09:02:09,cc,dd,y35,ee,ff,gg,YY250,hh,jj,237.624
aa,zzz,05-FEB-14.09:02:09,cc,dd,y35,ee,ff,gg,YY250,hh,jj,237.624
aa,zzz,11-JUN-13.05:06:17,cc,dd,y35,ee,ff,gg,YY250,hh,jj,476.787
aa,zzz,11-JUN-13.05:06:17,cc,dd,y35,ee,ff,gg,YY250,hh,jj,476.787
aa,zzz,11-JUN-13.05:06:17,cc,dd,y35,ee,ff,gg,YY250,hh,jj,476.787
```

I don't have the access to change the input format and dont have perl & python access.

**Update#3:**

```
BEGIN{ FS=OFS=","} 
{ 
t1=$3
t2="01-OCT-14.00:00:00"
print $0,(cvttime(t2) - cvttime(t1))/24/3600
}

function cvttime(t,     a) {
        split(t,a,"[-.:]")
        match("JANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC",a[2])
        a[2] = sprintf("%02d",(RSTART+2)/3)
        return( mktime("20"a[3]" "a[2]" "a[1]" "a[4]" "a[5]" "a[6]) )
}
```

Comment: Ed Morton, you are really Great Man with Good Stuff, the new script is taking time 16 seconds only  in Cygwin where as the old script used to take 50 Mins for  one lac rows !!!

Comment: Ed Morton, I have accepted the answer and up-voted !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are on cygwin you are using GNU awk which has it's own built-in time functions and so you do not need to be trying to use the shell `date` command. Just tweak this old command I had lying around to suit your input and output format:

```
function cvttime(t,     a) {
        split(t,a,"[/:]")
        match("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",a[2])
        a[2] = sprintf("%02d",(RSTART+2)/3)
        return( mktime(a[3]" "a[2]" "a[1]" "a[4]" "a[5]" "a[6]) )
}
BEGIN{
t1="01/Dec/2005:00:04:42"
t2="01/Dec/2005:17:14:12"
print cvttime(t2) - cvttime(t1)
}
```

It uses GNU awk for time functions, see http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Time-Functions

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example in Perl:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV;
use Time::Piece;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new;
my $te = Time::Piece->strptime('01-OCT-14', '%d-%b-%y');
my $fn = 'Input.csv';
open (my $fh, '<', $fn) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!\n";
chomp(my $head = <$fh>);
say "$head,Ageing-NoOfDays";
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    chomp $line;
    if ($csv->parse($line)) {
        my $t = ($csv->fields())[2];
        my $tp = Time::Piece->strptime($t, '%d-%b-%y.%T');
        my $s = $te - $tp;
        say "$line," . $s->days;
    } else {
        warn "Line could not be parsed: $line\n";
    }
}
close($fh);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Hakon Haegland for your inputs , unfortunately i dont have perl installed in my office laptop !!!