# Need help reformatting date format in a csv

Tags: regex, awk, sed, hive

Thanks in advance for your help.

I have a Pipe Seperated File of about 800 MB with the following format:

```
120940|647002FC291C|wr741ndv4|scrubbedretail-manc|86.169.22.28|14-OCT-14 03.06.01.000000000|router|scrubbedretail|SCRUBBED|BBSLT_UPTO_8M_WBC|192.168.1.64|192.168.1.64|192.168.1.254|email@scrubbed.com|NULL|8|NULL|01416442367|13-OCT-14 00.00.00.000000000|120940|676392||Cons|BBEU06998225|16M|Broadband Option 3|Home Hub 30 Type A|Manchester|Preston|GW/BUS-20348838||WSBUS|IPSV00011090|G||NULL||N|Whitebox|7424|NULL|13-OCT-14 00.00.00.000000000
120934|647002FC3104|wr741ndv4|scrubbedretail-manc|81.152.180.225|14-OCT-14 03.03.08.000000000|router|scrubbedretail|SCRUBBED|BBSLT_UPTO_8M_WBC|192.168.1.73|192.168.1.73|192.168.1.254|none@scrubbed.com|NULL|8|NULL|01236872185|13-OCT-14 00.00.00.000000000|120934|675954||Cons|BBEU06326286|16M|Broadband Option 3|Home Hub 40 Type A|Manchester|Preston|GLG-20285887||WSGLG|IPSV00009974|A||NULL||N|Whitebox|4640|NULL|13-OCT-14 00.00.00.000000000
```

I need to convert the date formats from DD-MMM-YY HH.MM.SS.sssssssss into yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.   Ideally, I would like to use the command line.  Any thoughts on how to do this?   sed or awk?

EDIT:   Sorry if you all believe this is a duplicate question.   However, my problem is wading through the Pipe Separated File to obtain the correct date data to pipe into the date command, and then piping it back out...

Comment: I dont think you can do this with a regex. Converting `MMM` -> `MM` would be problematic at least.

Comment: Why do we need to read lines that are 50-ish fields long just to convert dates from one format to another? Post some input that's got, say, 5 fields instead so people trying to help you don't have to wade through a bunch of irrelevant information.

Comment: Ed,  Sorry ---- part of my problem is programmatically wading through the PSV to select the correct fields, editing them, and then returning them to the proper placement in the file

Answer (score 0):

To convert from one date format to another, just modify the answer posted at https://stackoverflow.com/a/27659933/1745001 to suit your input format.